# NSUrlRequest: where an app can find the default headers for HTTP request?

Tags: cocoa, ios, macos, core-foundation

Does anybody know where an iOS app can see the default headers that `NSUrlRequest` sets for an HTTP request?

Just creating `NSUrlRequest` with *"http://.."* `NSURL` and then asking: `[request allHTTPHeaderFields]` returns an empty dictionary. But [I know](http://blog.mro.name/2009/06/nsurlconnection-gzip-magic/) that for example *"Accept-Encoding"* is set to *"gzip"*. So I want to get all that fields and show them in a HTTP request demo.

I've also tried to [swizzle](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling) `[NSMutableURLRequest setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:]`, but it seems that it is not used by underlying API (NSURLRequest or NSURLConnection) to set those default fields I'm hunting for.

I'm making just a simple iOS demo which shows HTTP request and response information, so it doesn't really matters if it will be a public or private API used for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may be an overkill, but based on [Matt Gallagher's blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html) I've created even more simpler local HTTP listener and sent a separate [mutableCopy]ed request to it to be able to read and output all HTTP headers that this request has.

Better solution must be to setup a local HTTP request catcher, it must look nicer I think, but for the scope of simple demo just to show all sent/received headers this solution is OK.

Answer (score 14):

Your app cannot.  It's done all down in [CFNetwork - Communicating with HTTP Servers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFHTTPTasks/CFHTTPTasks.html). I believe it just adds missing header values not supplied by [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The defaults are:

- **USER-AGENT** "AppName - Eng/1.0 CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/10.7.0"
- **ACCEPT** "*/*"
- **ACCEPT-LANGUAGE** "en-us"
- **ACCEPT-ENCODING** "gzip, deflate"
- **CONNECTION** "keep-alive"

Comment: There is also **HOST** "host:port";

Answer (score 5):

hmm... maybe you might want to try within

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```

method in your custom nsurlconnection class. although the documentation mentions something about redirects, this is certainly worth looking into.

Comment: Nice shot, but unfortunately not 100% hit.

Comment: Indeed `-(NSURLRequest *)connection:willSendRequest: redirectResponse:` will be called for a simple request when no redirection is needed (despite official docs) and its header will have some fields at this stage:
`{ Accept = "*/*"; Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate"; Accept-Language" = "en-us";}` but there more: "Host", "User-Agent" and "Connection" which are set at some lower level - I've run a simple local HTTP server to see all of them.