# NSMutableURLRequest, cant access all request headers sent out from within my iPhone program

Tags: ios, iphone, http-headers, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I am creating an iPhone http client that sends out 2 headers with its POST (or GET).
My server receives 7 headers.
The network library added 5 headers.
**Is there a way to access the added headers from within the ios program?**
or
**Is there a way to suppress this feature and have it not add headers to the request?**
I can already do this with external tools.
I just need the ios program to record all headers being sent out.

Here are all the ugly details:

code that sent the request from my iPhone:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  

[request setValue:@"BlahAgent" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSLog(@"all headers %@",request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
```

this prints to xcode console:

```
all headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "User-Agent" = "BlahAgent";
}
```

on the receiving end (php) I run

```
$allHeaders = getallheaders();
print_r($allHeaders)
```

and get:

```
Array
(
    [Host] => 192.168.0.15
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Accept] => */*
    [Accept-Language] => en-us
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Content-Length] => 0
    [User-Agent] => BlahAgent
)
```

I even did a wire shark and got:

```
POST /php/ajax.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.15
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: BlahAgent
```

I did it again but with GET and no headers and got:

```
[Host] => 192.168.0.15
[Connection] => keep-alive
[Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
[User-Agent] => Blah%20Agent/1.0 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0
[Accept-Language] => en-us
[Accept] => */*
```

Comment: I didn't state it explicitly but I need to see the outgoing headers from within the program that is sending the request.        I need progamatic access to the request headers that were added by the networking library.     

Sorry that I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, try a web debugging tool such as: [fiddler](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.telerik.com/fiddler&ei=Icf5UrKEB6rwyAHOzoHYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGY5eqyh8uRUDSYsPDDbTNL4aUgVw) if you are runninng on windows, or [charles](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.charlesproxy.com/&ei=Jcf5UpX0DKT4yQHTlIGADA&usg=AFQjCNG_O70VsRrfb_q7F66Nkb9ZK6MNMA&bvm=bv.61190604,d.aWc) if you have a mac. With any of those you can inspect the whole details of any request being sent, given that he stands as a proxy for every connection sent through http.

**EDIT**: Also, note that the remaining headers you are not setting are automatically given by the HTTP protocol, since they are required in a transaction.

Comment: I can already read the request headers externally but I need to read them from the app that is making the request.  I did a telnet session and the only header needed was host:    thanks for the input anyway.  I'm sure that ios has a way to read the outgoing headers that were added, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Its looking like what I want **can't be done**.
 
[discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695914/nsurlrequest-where-an-app-can-find-the-default-headers-for-http-request)

You can setup a local server send the request to it and have it send back the full request,
but that is sort of Rube Goldburg-ish.
or
You can problably use a lower level library without the magic elves doing stuff for you.